# Send push notifications from AIR desktop client without middleware (eg. PHP)

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, air, openssl, apple-push-notifications

With this PHP code:

```
<?php
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsCert = 'apns-dev.pem';
$apnsPort = 2195;

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'Oh hai!', 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
$output = json_encode($payload);
$token = pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $token))
$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . $token . chr(0) . chr(strlen($output)) . $output;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);

?>
```

you can send a push notification using PHP. From an AIR desktop client I can easily pass POST variables to a similar code and use AS3+PHP to send a notification.

The question: is it theoretically possible to do the same by only using AS3 and AIR (that is without PHP)? Has anyone tried? Aside from firewall issues, what could eventually cause problems? Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about pushing notifications directly between clients?

Comment: I simply would like to know if I can convert the above PHP code to AS3 (yes, direcly opening the socket from an AIR desktop app).

Comment: You can use XMLSocket http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/XMLSocket.html from within ActionScript, but where **to** would you open the socket? You'd still need server side code...

Comment: No, I think XMLSocket is not the way: I was thinking I need SecureSocket or DatagramSocket. The socket is opened the same way as PHP does. Moreover, the socket should do the same PHP does with the .pem certificate here.

Answer (score 1):

The [NetGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetGroup.html) class is ideal for this. You can send anything you want from device A to device B and vice versa, or even multiple devices. It works sort of like a chatroom, but is not limited to strings.

If the devices are not on the same network, they'll need to be introduced to eachother via the Adobe Cirrus server (free for testing and non-commercial use) or another FMS server (such as an Adobe or Amazon hosted service, or your own server). Once introduced they normally communicate directly to eachother via the rtmfp secure peer-to-peer protocol, which can traverse almost all firewalls. In the rare case that they cannot connect directly the FMS server can relay the messages.

Comment: As you can see from the code, I'm not contacting another device directly: the code uses a socket to a server, then the server sends notification to devices (if this server confirms you can: that's the reason for the .pem file).

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I'm off target here, but have you looked at ANE's?

There is an iOS ANE that looks like it lets you send a native push from your handheld without php.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12